# Solspace User forgot password returns error: "Unable to send email at this time"

Tags: solspace, solspace-user, postmaster, forgot-password

With Solspace User the forgot password function is returning the EE form error: **"Unable to send email at this time."**.

However, the forgot password email **is being sent** to the member who requested it.

I'm using Postmaster to send all system emails (through Mandrill) if that makes a difference.

**What would cause that error to display, even if the email is being sent correctly?**

Comment: What version of EE/User are you using? Sounds like something Mandrill/Postmaster might be throwing (could be wrong). Have you tried the forgot password form *without* Postmaster installed and/or *without* using Mandrill?

Comment: I am getting this issue right now as well. It just started happening. I am looking into it now. I have no idea what the issue is. It might be something to do with Mandrill, but I am not sure yet. I know there was no issue last week with this.

Comment: http://status.mandrillapp.com/

Comment: Justin, I don't see any mandrill status problems but the new version of Postbox you emailed me seems to have fixed the issue.